# Restricted circular Permutations

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> The number of ways in which 5 boys and 4 girls can be arranged on a circular table such that no two girls sit together and two particular boys are always together is _______ .

I find the answer is $(4-1)! × 2!  × 4! = 288$.

But the doubt I have is that for selecting 2 boys out of 5 boys we have $\binom{5}{2}$ ways right? Why didn't we consider it? Is it because of the word "particular"?

Comment: Short answer: Yes.

Comment: Your answer is correct.